# App crashes whenn setting an onClickListener?

Tags: android, button, crash, onclick, android-viewpager

Hi everybody I'm struggling a strange problem.
I changed my ViewFlipper to ViewPager and since there my App crashed. I found out that it's not the Viewpager that crashes but the button.setOnClickListener method. I commented out everything else so I noticed that the App works fine if I'm commenting out my two Buttons with that method. And it's not the thing inside onClick(), I treied it out and it crashes even if it's empty.but here is some code of the one im fighting with:

```
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);




    MyPagerAdapter adapter = new MyPagerAdapter();
        ViewPager myPager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.pager);
        myPager.setAdapter(adapter);
        myPager.setCurrentItem(1);
    new Toolbox();    

push = (Button)findViewById(R.id.pushbutton);
             push.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {


                public void onClick(View v) {
                    head=head_field.getText().toString();
                    note=note_field.getText().toString();
                    try {
                        Toolbox.createTask(userToken,task, Dashboard_id, head, note, service);
                        head_field.setText("");
                        note_field.setText("");
                    } catch (ProducteevException e) {
                        return;

                    }
                }
            });
```

this is the button xml excerpt:

```
<Button
             android:id="@+id/pushbutton"
             android:layout_width="200dp"
             android:layout_height="200dp"
             android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
             android:layout_marginTop="35dp"
             android:background="@drawable/push_button" />
```

and here the LogCat

```
01-12 20:50:24.402: W/dalvikvm(28405): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015578)
01-12 20:50:24.402: E/AndroidRuntime(28405): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-12 20:50:24.402: E/AndroidRuntime(28405): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{producteev.push/producteev.push.Producteev_pushActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-12 20:50:24.402: E/AndroidRuntime(28405):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1651)
01-12 20:50:24.402: E/AndroidRuntime(28405):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1667)
01-12 20:50:24.402: E/AndroidRuntime(28405):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
01-12 20:50:24.402: E/AndroidRuntime(28405):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:935)
01-12 20:50:24.402: E/AndroidRuntime(28405):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-12 20:50:24.402: E/AndroidRuntime(28405):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
01-12 20:50:24.402: E/AndroidRuntime(28405):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
01-12 20:50:24.402: E/AndroidRuntime(28405):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-12 20:50:24.402: E/AndroidRuntime(28405):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
01-12 20:50:24.402: E/AndroidRuntime(28405):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:842)
01-12 20:50:24.402: E/AndroidRuntime(28405):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
01-12 20:50:24.402: E/AndroidRuntime(28405):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-12 20:50:24.402: E/AndroidRuntime(28405): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-12 20:50:24.402: E/AndroidRuntime(28405):    at producteev.push.Producteev_pushActivity.onCreate(Producteev_pushActivity.java:122)
01-12 20:50:24.402: E/AndroidRuntime(28405):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
01-12 20:50:24.402: E/AndroidRuntime(28405):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1615)
01-12 20:50:24.402: E/AndroidRuntime(28405):    ... 11 more
```

Would be amazing if somebody knows that Problem.

Comment: see this line 
01-12 20:50:24.402: E/AndroidRuntime(28405):    at producteev.push.Producteev_pushActivity.onCreate(Producteev_pushActivity.java:122)
this is your best friend, learn to look for you package name to find the cause of the crash

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure your push buton id is corect, it seems that your findViewById() returns null...

Comment: yeah it is right as you see here: push = (Button)findViewById(R.id.pushbutton);
== android:id="@+id/pushbutton"   but you're right, it returns null!!!

Comment: I see it, but you can make a break point at the line where you are setting the click listener and see if your push button object is null or not

Comment: If it returns null, please post your entire code so we can help you better

Comment: your button is on the layout xml main that you are setting as contentView?

Comment: solved it. Silly mistake. I changed my Main Layout when I added the Viewpager, so the Button is not in Main Anymore, so the findViewById couldn't find anything. Now I used a LayouInflater to get the right View. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Since I can't see the entirety of your code, it's hard to know for sure, but it appears that the error may be getting thrown upon creation, from your stacktrace.  Since nothing happens within the onClick() method, the only other thing I can think of is the fact that `push` must be null, from the code you have posted.  This may be caused, if that is the issue, by either the ID being incorrect (the one being passed into the `findViewById()` call), or, if the compiler seems ok with the id you're passing in (I think it wouldn't compile otherwise) it may be the casting with `(Button)` that is not working properly.  I would check the type of your `R.id.pushbutton`'s actual class type and make sure that it is a `(Button)`.

Comment: yes of course as you see in the XML it's a Button, and Eclipse also says that the R.id.pushbutton is ok, and it's the right one as well.

Comment: Ah, right-- missed seeing your XML above... is it possible that you are overriding the findViewByID() method and something is not being returned in there? i.e. you're returning null from that override somehow?  Seeing more of your class in which this Java resides might make it easier to help debug if that's possible.

Comment: solved it. Silly mistake. I changed my Main Layout when I added the Viewpager, so the Button is not in Main Anymore, so the findViewById couldn't find anything. Now I used a LayouInflater to get the right View. Thanks a lot